# Gap on top after each post

Tags: css

I am working on a website and I want to make the blog page look like that of [Mashable](http://mashable.com). I styled the post items with the following css,

```css
#mashable{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```

They do show horizontally but after each post there is an increased [gap on the top](http://supportseekers.info/680-2/). Please guide me how can I remove it.

Thanks.

Note: Thanks for pointing out the `<br>` tag. I have removed it from the code.

Comment: You have <br> tag there

Comment: Also, you have repeated id of "mashable". Change it to class, as ID should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

there's `<br>` after every `<span id="mashable"></span>` remove it

Answer (score 0):

add to your css this code in css `vertical-align: top;` or remove your `<br>` tag before your `<span>` tag